# Custom dataset is much slower than built in one

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, python-class

I made a custom "Dataset" class, to use with training a GAN. Just for a benchmark, I decided to get the MNIST dataset in .png format, and used my dataset to fetch a 10000 images iteratively in a for loop. (meaning, calling dataset[i] for i in range(10000) )

Then I did the same thing using the built-in dataset as:

```
datasets.FashionMNIST('.',train = True)
```

Comparing the time each of them took, mine is slower by a factor of roughly 10. I'm concerned this might noticeably slow down the training of the GAN. Is data loading a bottleneck usually?

I am wondering if it is my implementation which is bad, or if it is simply the dataformat that is slowing down the process (given that my dataset loads from .png images, while the built-in one has a special file format).

Here is my implementation:

```
import torch.utils.data as tdata
import torch
import os
from torchvision.io import read_image

class GANDataset(tdata.Dataset):
    """
        Dataset for training GANs. Simply contain data for images, without
        any label.

        Parameters : 
        img_directory : str
            directory containing the images of the dataset
            @@@ Maybe add automatic dezipping ?@@@

    """

    def __init__(self, img_directory, transform = None):
        super().__init__()

        self.dir = img_directory
        self.transfo = transform
        self.filelist = [name for name in os.listdir(self.dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(self.dir,name))]
        self.length = len(self.filelist)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.length

    def __getitem__(self, idx : int):
        sample = self.load(os.path.join(self.dir,self.filelist[idx]))
        if self.transfo :
            sample = self.transfo(sample)

        return sample

    def load(self,path):
        """ 
            Load image to pytorch tensor from path
        """
        #img = Image.open(path)
        #img = transforms.ToTensor()(img)
        img = read_image(path)  

        return img
```

Edit : After experimenting a bit more with `Image.open`, I realised there is very high variance in the time it takes to load the images. It ranges from 10 to 100 times slower than the built-in version. Curiously I did not observe this variance with read_image. It has probably to do with the fact that I have the 60k images in png format in a folder, but if somebody is more knowledgeable I would love to know more.

Comment: Note that if I try to load the image in PIL format, namely using `img = Image.open(path)`, it is just as slow, if not slower !